# Como alterar nome de ficheiro com variavel

Tags: php, string, variáveis

Este é o ficheiro com a variável que pretendo.

```
# pt/lang.php
<?PHP
$rp_lang = "pt";
?>
```

Este é o ficheiro que quero inserir mas quero que a variável altere o final ou para "pt" ou "en" ou outra qualquer.

```
# inc/saudacao_pt.php
<?PHP
$rp_saudacao = "Olá bom dia";
?>
```

Esta é o ficheiro que vem a público.

```
# pt/index.php
<?php
include_once '../pt/lang.php';

include_once '../inc/saudacao_".$rp_lang.".php';
?>
```

Se substituir `".$rp_lang."` por "pt" funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Ocorre algum erro? Não dá o resultado esperado? Dê mais detalhes. Experimentou usar parenteses no nome? Sei lá o PHP é meio esquisito. realmente você está usando apóstrofe e aspas misturado assim?

Comment: sim coloquei parenteses escrevi pasta por escrever o nome dela é pt já vou alterar o poste

Comment: Não dá erro simplesmente não assume a pasta "saudacao_pt.php" e todo o seu conteúdo mas se substituir ".$rp_lang." por "pt" em "index.php" funciona perfeitamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está na concatenação. Você não está fechando as aspas simples para concatenar a variável e as aspas duplas são desnecessárias.

Faça assim:

```
include_once '../inc/saudacao_' . $rp_lang . '.php';
```

Comment: Obrigado @Lucas não me tinha apercebido desse pormenor.

Comment: @RjpServidor eu escrevi no meu comentário, você não prestou atenção.

Answer (score 3):

Resolvi responder porque eu tinha resolvido no comentário. Você misturou o apóstrofe com aspas. O correto:

```
include_once '../inc/saudacao_' . $rp_lang . '.php';
```

ou

```
include_once "../inc/saudacao_$rp_lang.php";
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/XbrM7I). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/StringDelimiterphp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/StringDelimiter.php).